# wp media uploader not responsive in small screen

Tags: wordpress, plugins

In my plugin I use the following code to enqueue all of the necessary CSS, JS & HTML markup for media uploader.

```
<?php

add_action("admin_enqueue_scripts","scripts_for_newsletter");
 function scripts_for_newsletter(){
   
   if(get_current_screen()->id == "toplevel_page_newsletter"){
     wp_enqueue_media();
   }
   
 }
```

Media uploader work but in small screen( my android phone ) it is like:
[image]

When dextop mode is enable then the media uploader looks good.
[image: at dextop view]
[image: dextop mode enabled]
Using wordpress 5.8. Can it be fixed or it is normal?

Comment: seems to me it is a bug in the media uploader. tested this in a website I mange using the set featured image and it does exactly the same thing.

Comment: tested in another website using running on 5.6.4 and there it works correct so it is a bug perhaps since 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in 5.8 and as far as I can tell it will be fixed in 5.8.1

source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53679#comment:2